# Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Cannot access execution context

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

How do I access execution context in my program to capture screenshot ?
The following program will fail since contain text does not exist.

```
from ExtendedSelenium2Library import ExtendedSelenium2Library
import logging

class firsttest():


    def googleit(self):
        self.use_url = 'https://google.ca'
        self.use_browser = 'chrome'

        s2l = ExtendedSelenium2Library()
        s2l.open_browser(self.use_url, self.use_browser)
        s2l.maximize_browser_window()

        try:
            # Should fail
            s2l.page_should_contain('this text does not exist on page')
        except:
            logger.debug('failed')


runit = firsttest()
runit.googleit()
```

When I run this program get warning

```
WARNING - Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Cannot access execution context
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use robot to execute the test, you can't just instantiate classes and expect them to work. They are designed to work only when run by robot.

If you need to write tests in python, there's no need to use `ExtendedSeleniumLilbrary`, you can just call the selenium API directly from python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely stems from the fact that you did not write your python Library in the correct format for Robot Framework.

Here is the correct format for writing Python code in Robot Framework:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class ClickAnElement(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.selenium_lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ExtendedSelenium2Library')

    def click_an_element(self, locator):
        BuiltIn().click_element(locator)
```

How this works (I believe) is in Robot Framework you call this library in your `*** Settings ***` section with `Library     ClickAnElement.py`. That activates the `__init__` function. Then you can call the keywords like you would a keyword from Selenium2Library. So, if I were to re-write your posted code in the correct format, it would look as follows:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import logging

class FirstTest():
    def __init__(self):
        self.selenium_lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ExtendedSelenium2Library')

    def google_it(self):
        self.use_url = 'https://google.ca'
        self.use_browser = 'chrome'
        s2l = ExtendedSelenium2Library()
        s2l.open_browser(self.use_url, self.use_browser)
        s2l.maximize_browser_window()
        try:
            # Should fail
            s2l.page_should_contain('this text does not exist on page')
        except:
            logger.debug('failed')
```

Then, my .robot file would look as such:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     FirstTest

*** Test Cases ***
Test Google It
    Google It
```

You were writing a Python file to work *outside* of Robot Framework. If you want it to work *inside* of Robot Framework, you need to use the correct Library format.

Mind you, I'm only formatting your code, not testing it. I can't, since I don't have your application to test it on.